# Linhas transparentes com CSS

Tags: css, css3

É possível fazer algo como isso apenas com CSS?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Thanks

Comment: Cara, eu acredito que sim, ai tu cria 7 div's, coloca como background essa imagem quadriculada e adiciona uma sombra no final de cada uma das div com a propriedade box-shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim amigo existem algumas formas de fazer, eu particularmente prefiro usando um pseudo-elemento `::after` como um `radial-gradient`

```css
.sombra {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sombra::after {    
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, transparent 70%, transparent 100%);
}
.sombra.scale::after {    
    transform: translate(0%, -50%) scaleY(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="sombra"></div>
<div class="sombra scale"></div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Tenho andado à procura de soluções e não consegui encontrar nada que se adaptasse ao que eu queria e o que o senhor fez salvou o meu dia!

Comment: @DanielLopes obrigado jovem, mas "senhor" está no céu! :D boa sorte ai!